# Partially click through Android activity

Tags: android, qt, android-layout, android-activity, java-native-interface

I'm developing an Android app in Qt 5.3 and since there is no webView component available to show the map in.

I'm trying to call an overlay activity (floating since I don't need full screen map) and show that map there. So I.e if I press button A the Qt app executes c++ class that calls out a native android activity with web view. That works nicely.

Problem appears when I want to navigate to another page with button B that is on main activity, behind the overlay activity. 
I managed to flag whole overlay as not_touchable *(getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);)* and then I was able to kill ( *finish()* ) the activity after clicking on button B but I still need to be able to use my webview normally.

I was wondering if I can make only part of the activity not_tocuhable by creating activity following way: Activity -> LinearLayout(vertical) -> TableRow (should be click through) and WebView (should be touchable). Since that description is quite messy please see the my "GREAT" drawing.

Anyways any help is appreciated and the solution doesn't have to be the way I was planning here. That was just an idea.

[image: My app activitys]

Answer (score 0):

Had a little eureka moment this morning while eating breakfast and browsing android reference docs. I can use **FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL** flag on secondary activity window and with that flag all the touches outside of activity go to background activity. So no weird workarounds needed there.